# Timeseries average with python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I looked at Panda and it might not be easy of use for my purpose.
Probably there is a python toolkit out there and I'm not aware of.
Could you tell me what package could easily deal with situations like the one described below?

I have a series of 2D numpy arrays of instant values of a meteorological variable (for a a geographical area), sampled at hours 0, 6, 12, ..., 96,... for a specific date.

I have it as a python dictionary:

```
values[0]:[[3, 2,...,9, 5][6, 7, ..., 6, 7]]
...
...
values[96]:[[2, 2,...,8, 5][6, 7, ..., 5, 6]]
```

I need to average on a configurable aggregation step. For example, for an aggregation step of 24 hours I would obtain 4 daily averages:

```
values_avg24h=average(values, aggr_step=24)
values_avg24h[24]=[[...][...]]
values_avg24h[48]=[[...][...]]
values_avg24h[72]=[[...][...]]
values_avg24h[96]=[[...][...]]
```

The time resolution can change. Also, original values can be averaged as well but on a different aggregation step. A specific existing package could solve all of that. Anyway, even a smart solution to this simple problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data are sampled at a regular frequency (which your post seems to indicate) then `pandas` certainly can help you.

One possible `pandas` solution is to create a `Panel` object where the `items` (like keys in your dictionary) are of class `pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex`. The `major_axis` and `minor_axis` elements of the `Panel` will then be the rows, and columns in your numpy arrays. This sounds a bit strange, so I will show a quick example.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> start_date = '4/14/2013'  # Start today (default time is midnight)

# create the date_range we will use as panel items
>>> ind = pd.date_range(start=start_date, periods=20, freq='6H')

# Create data: thanks @mtadd
>>> values = {h:np.array([np.random.random_integers(1,10,5) for _ in 'x'*2])
              for h in np.r_[0:120:6]}

# Create the Panel object directly from the dict of 2D np.arrays
>>> my_panel = pd.Panel(values)

# Set the Panel's items to be the date_range we made earlier
>>> my_panel.items = ind

>>> my_panel.ix[0]  # Show first 2D array of data
        0   1   2   3  4
     0  4   3  10   6  6
     1  4  10   7  10  6
>>> values[0]  # Same as above, but from the dict
    array([[ 4,  3, 10,  6,  6],
           [ 4, 10,  7, 10,  6]])
```

Now that we have things set up we will be using the `Panel` method `resample`. We will supply two arguments, the first will be the new frequency we want the data to be at and the second is a keyword argument `how` that we wil specify as `mean`.  ***This is the main part of my answer!***

```
>>> averaged = my_panel.resample('24H', how='mean')
>>> list(averaged.items)  # Show new time stamps for data
    [<Timestamp: 2013-04-14 00:00:00>,
     <Timestamp: 2013-04-15 00:00:00>,
     <Timestamp: 2013-04-16 00:00:00>,
     <Timestamp: 2013-04-17 00:00:00>,
     <Timestamp: 2013-04-18 00:00:00>]
```

Note that the `'24H'` parameter we gave the `resample` method was simply an extension of the example posted by the OA. See [this link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) for more information on what types of descriptions this argument can take.

To verify that the mean was calculated correctly we will compare the first item in the `averaged` `Panel` to the mean we calculate by hand.

```
>>> averaged.ix[0]
         0     1     2     3     4
    0  6.5  5.25  7.25  6.25  6.50
    1  5.0  6.75  5.25  6.50  5.25

>>> (values[0] + values[6] + values[12] + values[18]) / 4.
    array([[ 6.5 ,  5.25,  7.25,  6.25,  6.5 ],
           [ 5.  ,  6.75,  5.25,  6.5 ,  5.25]])
```

You can have much more flexibility over the time stamps for the `items` if you pass a `datetime.datetime` object in. For example, if you started sampling on New Years's Day at 1:37 PM and continued sampling for 50 periods you could do this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> start = datetime(2013, 1, 1, 13, 37)  # 1:37 on 1/1/2013
>>> ind = pd.date_range(start, periods=50, freq='6H')
```

Then you would carry on as before. You can also pass starting and ending items to date_range instead of the number of periods you want it to generate. If we collected data every 2 1/2 hours from the same starting time as above until 4:50 AM on February 28th, you could do the following:

```
>>> end = datetime(2013, 2, 28, 4, 50)  # 4:50 AM on 2/28/2013
>>> ind = pd.date_range(start, freq='2H 30MIN')
```

Notice that you don't have to pass starting and ending times that align perfectly with the frequency you passed in. For more details on how to work with the [`Panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#panel) object or [time series data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html) in `pandas` check out the links given in those words.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. 
Yes, they always come with a regular frequency (3H, 6H, 12H...). I will try it. Do you think is possible to perform accumulation as well? Or, supposing original data are cumulated over a (e.g.) 6H period, producing (e.g.) 24H cumulated values? Ideally, I could be able to perform all combinations:

-averages from instantaneous|averaged|cumulated samples
-cumulations from instantaneous|averaged|cumulated samples

Cheers!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by accumulation, but the `how` parameter in `resample` can take function names or numpy array functions that returns an aggregated form of the input array. For example you could pass in, `np.sum`, `np.max`, `np.min`, `np.prod`, ect. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html?highlight=downsampling#up-and-downsampling) for more examples.

Comment: to get 24h (24H=1D) cumulated sums, using @spencerlyon2's code above, `pd.resample('D',how='sum').cumsum(axis=0)`

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

def average(values, aggr_step=24):
    keys = np.array(values.keys())
    bins = range(aggr_step,1+keys.max(),aggr_step)
    npd = np.digitize(keys,bins)
    return {b:np.mean(np.r_[[values[k] for k in keys[npd==i]]],axis=0)
            for i,b in enumerate(bins)}
```

Whip up some sample values, and test:

```
values = {h:np.array([np.random.random_integers(1,10,5) for _ in 'x'*2])
          for h in np.r_[0:100:6]}

{0: array([[ 1,  2, 10,  8,  7],
       [10,  1,  8,  2,  5]]),
 6: array([[ 7, 10,  7,  6,  4],
       [ 9,  4,  6,  1,  1]]),
 12: array([[ 7, 10, 10,  5,  4],
       [ 7,  6,  2,  6,  7]]),
 18: array([[9, 9, 8, 5, 8],
       [8, 9, 6, 1, 2]]),
 24: array([[8, 1, 5, 9, 7],
       [1, 1, 6, 8, 3]]),
 30: array([[ 7,  2,  8,  3,  4],
       [ 5, 10,  5,  6,  5]]),
 36: array([[ 6,  5,  9,  4,  5],
       [ 6, 10,  8, 10, 10]]),
 42: array([[ 2,  2,  6,  6,  9],
       [ 5,  7,  4,  8, 10]]),
 48: array([[10,  1,  1,  1,  8],
       [ 5,  6,  4,  5,  8]]),
 54: array([[ 6,  2,  6,  6,  6],
       [10,  6,  9,  4,  8]]),
 60: array([[ 6,  8,  2,  1,  7],
       [ 1, 10, 10,  2,  3]]),
 66: array([[4, 8, 7, 1, 3],
       [1, 3, 8, 4, 2]]),
 72: array([[ 8,  9,  8,  6,  7],
       [ 1,  4,  2, 10,  1]]),
 78: array([[ 2,  1,  3,  8,  9],
       [ 2,  8,  6, 10,  3]]),
 84: array([[ 1,  8,  9,  4,  3],
       [ 9, 10,  8,  3,  4]]),
 90: array([[ 4,  4,  2,  8,  6],
       [ 1,  3, 10,  2,  6]]),
 96: array([[ 9,  9,  8,  4,  4],
       [ 2,  8, 10,  3,  5]])}

average(values,24)

{24: array([[ 6.  ,  7.75,  8.75,  6.  ,  5.75],
       [ 8.5 ,  5.  ,  5.5 ,  2.5 ,  3.75]]),
 48: array([[ 5.75,  2.5 ,  7.  ,  5.5 ,  6.25],
       [ 4.25,  7.  ,  5.75,  8.  ,  7.  ]]),
 72: array([[ 6.5 ,  4.75,  4.  ,  2.25,  6.  ],
       [ 4.25,  6.25,  7.75,  3.75,  5.25]]),
 96: array([[ 3.75,  5.5 ,  5.5 ,  6.5 ,  6.25],
       [ 3.25,  6.25,  6.5 ,  6.25,  3.5 ]])}
```

Comment: Nice piece of code. I will go with pandas but I take into account to implement short aggregation methods if pandas doesn't fit perfectly.